# iPhone "Web Site Error"

Tags: iphone, encoding, utf-8

I'm writing server-side programs in PHP for an iPhone app. And I have no iPhone. :P

The iPhone app requests XML files from the site whenever a user runs the iPhone app. You may visit http://www.appvee.com/iphone/ads or http://www.appvee.com/iphone/latest for the XML files.

And a message box will show up with the following error messages:
"Web Site Error
Conversion of data failed. The file is not UTF-8, or in the encoding specified in XML header if XML.
"
[image]

Maybe I must add header("Content-type: text/xml"); at the beginning of the PHP files? I didn't add this line and it worked well before.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with ceejayoz, looks like this is a special characters issue.

I would suggest using the [htmlentities](http://us.php.net/htmlentities) method to encode the data in the xml file.

Answer (score 3):

It might be the unescaped special character (looks like it's supposed to be a curly apostrophe) in the 'latest' XML. (in the line that goes "Find out information about what[THIS IS THE CHARACTER]s around you and how...")

Does adding an XML content type header resolve the issue? You ask it if's necessary but give no indication if it helps or not.